# Why the variance of x is 1/4 for a uniform distribution range in 0 to 1?

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry

[image]

[Pls read page 14](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/chap1-high-dim-space.pdf)

Why not Var$(x) = \frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: $1/12$ is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(X)=\int_0^1 x dx = \frac12$$
$$E(X^2)=\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac13$$
$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2=\frac13-(\frac12)^2=\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: Looking  a bit into the paper mentioned, it doesn't look like the error made there is material, it is even in the paper's disadvantage. The main conclusion is some probability being at least $1-\frac1{4t^2}$ when the correct calculation gives the better  $1-\frac1{12t^2}$

Comment: @Ingix Thank you for your explanation.